# MySql Big Data With Multiple Select

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I have an MySQL database with a table named "foo". Foo has ~50.000.000 records. What i wanna do is select all the records with multiple queries. For example i'd like to get the first 5000 record first, then do [something] with it, then get the next 5000 record and repeat the process, until i'm finished. I can do it in small parts like this, because of memory limitations. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Cursors are one. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/   Also, I'm not sure I'd consider only 50m records Big Data

Comment: See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination